# Nginx, Ansible, and uWSGI with Flask App, Internal Server Error

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, flask, wsgi, ansible

I have deployed my app on EC2 using the software in the title, but I am getting an Internal Server Error. [Here](http://mattupstate.com/python/devops/2012/08/07/flask-wsgi-application-deployment-with-ubuntu-ansible-nginx-supervisor-and-uwsgi.html) is the tutorial I have been following.

Here is the error log for me trying to get on the application via the browser:

```
2014/02/17 19:48:29 [error] 26513#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tm    p/uwsgi.sock:", host: "ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Can you post your playbook/ansible command?

Comment: Paste the relevant includes from includes `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` and `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Ansible playbook is based on [Matt Wright's tutorial](https://github.com/mattupstate/ansible-tutorial/), then all you need to do is reboot after the installation. The playbook doesn't update supervisor with the new program it installs (which is actually the upstream uWSGI referred to by the log), so the program cannot be started.

Comment: This links works for me: http://mattupstate.com/blog/flask-wsgi-application-deployment-with-ubuntu-ansible-nginx-supervisor-and-uwsgi/